# Fast way to remove some parts from string

Tags: c#, string

From following string `String1` I want to remove everything before **"am"** and everything after **"Uhr"**

```
string String1 = "Angebotseröffnung am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr, Ort: Vergabestelle, siehe a).";
```

So at the end I have this string. **"am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr"**.

I am using this code but I know this is not a good approach. Can some one help me with better options.

```
String1 = String1.Replace("Angebotseröffnung", "");
String1 = String1.Replace("Ort", "");
String1 = String1.Replace("Vergabestelle", "");
String1 = String1.Replace("siehe", "");
String1 = String1.Replace("a)", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use Regex.Match.

```
string output = Regex.Match(String1, "am.*Uhr").Value;
```

But it will work only if you definitely have `am` and `Uhr` in your string.
Depending on your input you may require `am.*?Uhr` or `(?:a|p)m.*?Uhr` regex.

Comment: if you are using regex, why not use regex replace?

Comment: in this case there is no point in replace. You would need to use 2 replaces with positive lookahead for `am` and positive lookbehind for `Uhr` - unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Gusdor It's faster to rip out the part he wants than to remove the other parts.

Comment: @khellang Smells like premature optimization to me. You also assume that the sample is a good representation of the goal - the question states removal after all. If there are suddenly more distinct elements that need to be kept than elements that need removal, it is faster to replace. It all depends on the input.

Comment: @Gusdor If the short version provides the same functionality as the long version `string output = Regex.Replace(String1, ".+(?=am)|(?<=Uhr).+", string.Empty)` why would we bother with it?

Comment: Thanks @UlugbekUmirov your approach is very simple and efficient

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
var string1 = "Angebotseröffnung am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr, Ort: Vergabestelle, siehe a).";

var startIndex = string1.IndexOf("am"); // 18
var endIndex = string1.IndexOf("Uhr") + 3; // 42

// Get everything between index 18 and 42
var result = string1.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex); 

// result: "am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr"
```

Comment: `am` is too short to be fail-safe and `Substring` throws if either `startIndex` or `endIndex` was `-1` (not found).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I didn't say that this works for *all* cases. But it works in the case he specified.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is strict and always contains `Angebotseröffnung am` and `Uhr` this is the most efficient:

```
string String1 = "Angebotseröffnung am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr, Ort: Vergabestelle, siehe a).";
string result = null;
string startPattern = "Angebotseröffnung am ";
int start = String1.IndexOf(startPattern);
if (start >= 0)
{
    start += startPattern.Length;
    string endPattern = " Uhr";
    int end = String1.IndexOf(endPattern, start);
    if (end >= 0)
        result = String1.Substring(start, end - start + endPattern.Length);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking for a fast way and the one suggested by @Ulugbek Umirov is fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the format will always be the same =>

```
var r = new Regex("am \d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{4} Uhr");
var result = r.Match(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

if the string will always contain **am** and **Uhr**, and will always have **am** before **Uhr**:

```
string String1 = "Angebotseröffnung am 27.03.2014, 11:00 Uhr, Ort: Vergabestelle, siehe a).";

int indexOfAm = String1.IndexOf("am");
int indexOfUhr = String1.IndexOf("Uhr");

string final = String1.Substring(indexOfAm, (indexOfUhr + 3) - indexOfAm);
```

Answer (score 0):

With StringBuilder, Replace works the same way as with strings but it doesn't need its result to be assigned

```
class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
        const string samplestring = "hi stack Over Flow String Replace example.";

        // Create new StringBuilder from string

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(samplestring );



                // Replace the first word
                // The result doesn't need assignment
                str.Replace("hi", "hello");
                Console.WriteLine(b);
        }
        }

    Output Will be -->
    hello stack Over Flow String Replace example
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  String1 = String1.Substring(String1.IndexOf("am"), (String1.IndexOf("Uhr") - String1.IndexOf("am"))+3);
```